# AWS Cloudfront CORS trouble with font files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cors, css

I have a Javascript application that is delivered to the browser from a CloudFront endpoint. All static files of the application are hosted in an S3 bucket. That involves a whole bunch of javascript and css files, as well as some font files.

The html loading the entire application is generated and delivered by a server, let's call that server "https://my.domain.com".

As mentioned, this is just the html file. *All* static content is then downloaded from the cloudfront endpoint, which points to a bucket as its origin. Let's call these xxxx.cloudfront.net, and the bucket my-bucket.

As far as I understand it, pretty much any request from that generated html to the cloudfront endpoint is a CORS request, since the origin of the html is my.domain.com, and all the requested files are clearly not hosted on that domain.

So naturally, I went to set up all the CORS stuff. First of all the bucket is completely public, and it has the following CORS policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*",
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

And that seems to work, for everything... *except* the font files!
I probably should mention the folder structure of the bucket. It has three folders, production, development, and common. The contents of these should be rather self-explanatory. Common contains the fonts, as well as some 3rd party javascript libraries. Production and development contain the js and css for their respective environments.

In any case, *everything* loads, except the font files, for which I get the following error:

```
Access to font at 'https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/common/fonts/outline/budicon-classic.ttf?jdete2' from origin 'https://my.domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It struck me as extremely odd that *only* the font files would have this issue. Other files in the common folder seem to get loaded just fine, and if I just paste https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/common/fonts/outline/budicon-classic.ttf?jdete2 into my browser, it *works*.

The only difference seems to be that these files are not loaded from the html, but from the css via the @font-face thingy. Looking at the requests generated by the browser when loading the application, I can clearly see that for example the origin header is set, which it wasn't for requesting js or css files. Set-Fetch-Mode is set to "cors", while for the other files it was set to "no-cors".

In any case, I tried to fix the issue at the cloudfront side. First, I added the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to the origin configuration. Then I added a behaviour configuration for the origin to allow GET, HEAD, OPTIONS for the path pattern *.

And now... well, now I still have the same problem, and am completely out of ideas, though wondering about Why the request created by @font-face is formed so differently when compared to the requests for javascript and css resources, but most of all, what on earth I can do to load in them bloody fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was annoying, but I guess logical.

The fixes I posted above *do work*, but configuration changes do not invalidate the cloudfront cache. And since CORS errors are generated by the *browser*, cloudfront did cache that response, headers and all, since it couldn't see anything wrong with it.

Long story short: Invalidated cloudfront cache after configuration changes, now it works. ARGH!